# why doesn't my treeview pick up my xsl changes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I am using the treeview control included in asp.net 2.0.

I want to use an xsl file that I created (test3.xslt).

Why isn't the Treeview picking up the changes to the tree made with the xsl (in tw, I think) and displaying them?

tw has the changes made by the xslt transform...

The DataSourceID for my treeview is my xmldatasource (xmldatasource1).

Thanks,

blue

```
        argsList.AddParam("Groups_From_Logged_In_User","",myLocalGroups);

        XslCompiledTransform xslTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();

        xslTransform.Load("C:\\ANewBeginning3\\test3.xslt");
        StringWriter tw = new StringWriter();

        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:\\ANewBeginning3\\output.xml"))
        {
            xslTransform.Transform(xmldoc.CreateNavigator(), argsList, tw);

            XmlDataSource1.Data = tw.ToString();
        }
        XmlDataSource1.DataBind();           

    }
```

Comment: when do you expect the changes to be detected?

Comment: BTW, I assigned an xml datafile (treeview.xml) to xmldatasource, and attempt to use an xmlTransform.load to 'transform' it as above. xmldoc is a modified version of treeview.xml. I'm open to other approaches.

Comment: This is in the Page_load function in Site.Master in an ASP.NET page.

Comment: I expect the contents of the xmldoc object (which is a modified treeview.xml) to appear after the page_load event.

Comment: xmldatasource.EnableCaching is set to False.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out...

First, xmldatasource blocks any other xml if xmldatasource.DataFile is specified. I was using xmldatasource.data above AND specified the DataFile as well. (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.xmldatasource.data.aspx )

Second, do not specify the xslt file in xmldatasource either. I was trying to both transform it (using xslTransform) AND specify the same stylesheet in xmlDatasource.TransFormFile (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.xmldatasource.transformfile.aspx). Don't do both (unless you know why you're doing it.)